# Decode single field of object in a json array with argonaut/circe

Tags: json, argonaut

Suppose I have such json

```
{
  "sha": "some sha",
  "parents": [{
    "url": "some url",
    "sha": "some parent sha"
  }]
}
```

and such case class

```
case class Commit(sha: String, parentShas: List[String])
```

In play-json I could write the reads like this:

```
val commitReads: Reads[Commit] = (
  (JsPath \ "sha").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "parents" \\ "sha").read[List[String]]
)(Commit.apply _)
```

I'm looking for a equivalent way of decoding only the "sha" of "parent" in argonaut/circe but I haven't found any. "HCursor/ACursor" has downArray but from there on I don't know what to do. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither circe nor Argonaut keeps track of which fields have been read in JSON objects, so you can just ignore the extra `"url"` field (just as in Play). The trickier part is finding the equivalent of Play's `\\`, which circe doesn't have at the moment, although you've convinced me we need to add it.

First of all, this is relatively easy if you have a separate SHA type:

```
import io.circe.Decoder

val doc = """
{
  "sha": "some sha",
  "parents": [{
    "url": "some url",
    "sha": "some parent sha"
  }]
}
"""

case class Sha(value: String)

object Sha {
  implicit val decodeSha: Decoder[Sha] = Decoder.instance(_.get[String]("sha")).map(Sha(_))
}

case class Commit(sha: Sha, parentShas: List[Sha])

object Commit {
  implicit val decodeCommit: Decoder[Commit] = for {
    sha <- Decoder[Sha]
    parents <- Decoder.instance(_.get[List[Sha]]("parents"))
  } yield Commit(sha, parents)
}
```

Or, using Cats's applicative syntax:

```
import cats.syntax.cartesian._

implicit val decodeCommit: Decoder[Commit] = 
  (Decoder[Sha] |@| Decoder.instance(_.get[List[Sha]]("parents"))).map(Commit(_, _))
```

And then:

```
scala> import io.circe.jawn._
import io.circe.jawn._

scala> decode[Commit](doc)
res0: cats.data.Xor[io.circe.Error,Commit] = Right(Commit(Sha(some sha),List(Sha(some parent sha))))
```

But that's not really an answer, since I'm not going to ask you to change your model. :) The actual answer is a bit less fun:

```
case class Commit(sha: String, parentShas: List[String])

object Commit {
  val extractSha: Decoder[String] = Decoder.instance(_.get[String]("sha"))

  implicit val decodeCommit: Decoder[Commit] = for {
    sha <- extractSha
    parents <- Decoder.instance(c =>
      c.get("parents")(Decoder.decodeCanBuildFrom[String, List](extractSha, implicitly))
    )
  } yield Commit(sha, parents)
}
```

This is bad, and I'm ashamed it's necessary, but it works. I've just filed [an issue](https://github.com/travisbrown/circe/issues/256) to make sure this gets better in a future circe release.